# Is it possible to create something along the lines of an odbc.d directory?

Tags: configuration, directory, unixodbc, freetds

Many servers such as nginx, Apache httpd, as well as other services and tools like yum, supervisord, cron, etc allow you to place configuration files in a directory and add, remove, and change individual files rather than work on one monolithic configuration file.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same for unixODBC (and along with it, FreeTDS). This would allow me to add or remove database configurations on-the-fly rather than manipulating a single configuration file.

Sample use case: I have a web app deployed to a bunch of cloud instances, the web app includes the configuration files it needs for nginx and supervisord. After being installed, it automatically copies over the needed nginx and supervisor files to the correct directories and restarts those servers, meaning the site is up and running right away… **except** that it uses unixODBC so I end up having to insert (or modify) a configuration in the odbc file.

I realize since these are ini files an option is writing a short script that reads and then writes the configuration to the ini file using a config file reader/writer, but this seems a lot clumsier and riskier than being able to add or replace a file in /etc/odbc.d